# OutofmemoryError opening an empty activity

Tags: android, memory

I created an activity that opens another one, the new one only have a button that doesn't do anything yet, I don't understand how can I get this error. I find that people get it when using bitmaps, in this case I don't. 
I get this error then the second activity opens anyway after a while but completely blank.

```
08-13 08:30:42.279: E/art(2027): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 3404976 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027): Error reporting crash
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3404976 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:340)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)    
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)    
08-13 08:30:42.292: E/AndroidRuntime(2027):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Code to create it:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Pause.class));
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".Pause" >
    <Button        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="II" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it..

Comment: Are you using the emulator? Do you have enough RAM in your emulator?

Comment: Please show more code. The `startActivity()` call seems to be inside an event handler (I'm guessing because of the explicit reference to `Main.this`). The error seems to be while handling *another* exception, but you are simply not providing not enough information to diagnose the problem properly.

Comment: In deed, the intent is inside another one. I solve this using a dialog, any way I'm interested to know if it's possible to start a 3rd activity from a 2nd one and so on and finally get the data back to the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by uninstalling the whole ADK and downloading it from zero to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

There was same issue in my code - opening an activity led to this crash.

On inspection it was found that - setting text on a TextActivity led to this crash. The data written to TextActivity was fetched from a (Model) singleton class - which was resulting in an infinite loop in its constructor.